# how to print variable from laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling a php file using in laravel controller. While calling the file I passing few data using ajax call. I want to print the variable that is passed to the controller file. Below is my code-

```
function handleJSON(originePlaceID, destPlaceID){
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('waypoints'); //getting the values from input field
                var wayptArray = new Array();
                for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                    if(elements[i].value != "") {
                        wayptArray.push(elements[i].value);
                        }
                    }
                var JsonWaypt = JSON.stringify(wayptArray);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "placeIdApi",
                    data: {data : JsonWaypt, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'}, 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(places){
                        console.log(places);
                    }
                });
                }
```

My web.php file:

```
Route::get('/placeIdApi', 'placeId@index');
```

My controller file(placeId.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request){
        $values = $request->data; //I want to print this $values variable.

    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to print this $request or $values variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: define print? do you want to dump them to see the values or use them somewhere else?

Comment: Other than dump as answer by other, you can also use `print_r($values);`,

Comment: I want to do something with the $values variable in this controller itself. I can return the value to js and console.log it there. But I want to print it in the php file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purposes, the **dd** method would definitely be the best, so something like this should work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
    $values = $request->data;
    //Print the values
    dd($values);
}
```

To **see** the result of this print, open up your Browser's console and go to the **Networking** section. Check the packet related to your request. The **dd** content should be printed into the preview for your request packet.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to output the `$values` value as JSON to use in your AJAX request, it might be best to do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request){
        $values = $request->data; //I want to print this $values variable.
        return response()->json($values);
    }
}
```

That will allow your js function to use the data that is return in the response.

To just print out the value as others have suggested, you can use the `dd` function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request){
        $values = $request->data; //I want to print this $values variable.
        dd($values);
    }
}
```

Then you can navigate to your defined route `http://example.com/placeIdApi` to see the echo'd out data.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump $value like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request){
        $values = $request->data; //I want to print this $values variable.

        dd($values); // die and dump $values

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried dd function. But I am wondering where can I see the output? Do I need to redirect to any page?

Comment: You can navigate to your defined route in the browser:  http://example.com/placeIdApi and it should show you the output there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dump method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class placeId extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request){
        $values = $request->data; //I want to print this $values variable.

        dump($values); //  dump $values
       //OR JSON RESPONSE
        return response()->json($values);


    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried dd() function. But I am wondering where can I see the output? Do I need to redirect to any page?